# Interrupt jQuery's on("scroll")

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I couldn't find a better title to describe my problem.

On a one page site I use this script to detect where the user is reading and to update to menu:

```
$(document).on("load scroll",function(e) {
  var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
  var home = $('#home').position().top;
  var references = $('#references').position().top;
  var contact = $('#contact').position().top;
  if ( scroll_top < references || scroll_top == 0)
        {
            $('header nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('header nav a:first-of-type').addClass('active');
        } else if ( scroll_top > references && scroll_top < contact) {
            $('header nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('header nav a:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
        } else if( scroll_top > contact) {
            $('header nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('header nav a:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
        }
});
```

When the user clicks on one of the links in the navigation, this event is triggered:

```
$(function() {
  // scroll handler
  var scrollToAnchor = function( id ) {
    // grab the element to scroll to based on the name
    var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
    // if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
    if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) === "undefined" ) {
      elem = $("#"+id);
    }
    // if the destination element exists
    if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) !== "undefined" ) {
      // do the scroll
      scroll_animate = false;
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:elem.offset().top}, {duration:1000});
      scroll_animate =  true;
    }
  };
  // bind to click event
  $("a").click(function( event ) {
    // only do this if it's an anchor link
    if ( $(this).attr("href").match("#") ) {
      // cancel default event propagation
      event.preventDefault();
      // scroll to the location
      var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
      scrollToAnchor( href );
    }
  });
});
```

My Problem: When the user clicks on one link in the navigation, I do not want the site to behave like if the user scrolled manually. So I do not want every link "on the way" to get the class `active` but only the target link in the navigation.

I tried setting a global variable when a link is clicked and adding this condition to the "on scroll" listener, but it did not work.

Comment: You could add like an data attribute to `body` or something when a user clicks a link and remove it after the scrolling has finished, then in the event handler check if `body` has your data attribute with the right value

Comment: Did you try returning from the function if a specific element gets clicked?

Comment: @JordanDoyle: Good idea, I tried that. Now the class is not appended in any case. I also tried adding a class to the nav element. Result: On Load and when the user is scrolling, the class will not be added. Though, the class is appended when the smooth scroll is triggered by the `scrollToAnchor` function! Obviously, there seems to be a difference.

@coder006: I also tried that, but it didn't have any effect.